# Unlimited Online File Storage

Tags: web-services

Well, I would like to build a file hosting website just like other already did, but it is going to be something different by adding search engine, allowing download and upload in full speed for any user, and so on. Unfortunately the web hosting plans, which declared to support UNLIMITED SPACE rarely allows me to host files on those space. So what I need is the unlimited file storage service which could host all of my users' files. 
I found Amazon S3, already provides such service, but could anybody recommends me for other better ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't want to hammer good ideas, but if I understand correctly, you want to build a hosting service, yet you want to 'rent' the disk space and bandwidth. Which means - in other words - you want to outsource a part of the core business. Which is the fastest way to kill your business.

Everyone - you rent from - will put their profit in the price you get, so it is possible to create a service this way, it would just be too expensive to sell.

I suggest you put spreadsheet together, where you calculate this service, like you would build it up piece by piece. Calculate the needed disk space (amount of disks), bandwidth, servers, and you will realize that with even 1000 user online you would need a smaller data center.

Comment: Thanks to karatedog for your good suggestion. I am now just investigating on the biz plan i am going to invest my budget in. For a startup phase, I would just need a small enough storage, and bandwidth. Do you know any web hosting plan, which allows file hosting feature?

Comment: Nope, I don't know such service

Answer (score 3):

No storage is really unlimited. Depending on how much space you'll need, this could get very expensive.